# Phonegap / Conexão com MySql Remoto sem PHP

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, apache-cordova

Gostaria de fazer uma conexão com um banco em MySQL remoto através de uma aplicação compilada para Phonegap sem a necessidade de usar o PHP. O banco não estaria dentro do dispositivo e sim na rede em que o dispositivo está conectado.

Alguns sites falam algo sobre utilizar o Node.js mas não entendi como faz e não consegui nenhum resultado.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer?

Gostaria de fazer sem PHP para evitar a instalação do servidor PHP na minha rede e a necessidade dessa linguagem para fazer a conexão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível. Projetos em Phonegap são feitos usando linguagem JavaScript que não possui funções de acesso direto ao banco de dados.

Sobre o NodeJS, ele é um ambiente que executa JavaScript no desktop. Devido as limitações do JavaScript ele foi extendido para suportar acesso ao Sistema de Arquivos, Streams, etc. Isso quer dizer que para seu aplicativo utilizar acesso ao banco de dados com NodeJS, você precisa do NodeJS no servidor para executar tal operação, e fazer com que seu aplicativo acesse um serviço NodeJS.